# Why this Read More Not working in Php?

Tags: php, get-the-title

Only that Read More issue is remaining.

```
<?php
            while(have_posts()): the_post();

         echo '<h2>'.get_the_title().'</h2>';
        echo  get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(),'medium');
        the_excerpt();
        echo "<br>";
        <a class="button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
        echo "<hr>";
        endwhile;
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Based on your last concern, here how I would do this.

The only problem left on your code is that you are calling some HTML inside PHP without `echo. So I split all those into seperates HTML tags and called them separatly in PHP.

```
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

        <figure class="thubmnail">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'medium'); ?>
        </figure>

        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

        <br/>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button">Read more</a>

        <hr/>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

---

You should really look at the WordPress Codex to understand how and when using those functions as your question is not clear.

Link to the documentation : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage

In your PHP file or Template file, you should have something like this (loop) to be able to show the value of `get_the_title()`and `the_permalink()`or it will display the parent page values.

```
<?php 
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As for your second issue, `the_title()` does not need to be in an `<?php echo ... ?>`. The function will echo itself. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title

> Displays or returns the unescaped title of the current post. This tag
>   may only be used within The Loop, to get the title of a post outside
>   of the loop use get_the_title. If the post is protected or private,
>   this will be noted by the words "Protected: " or "Private: " prepended
>   to the title

Hope it help you a little bit to clearly understand the concept.

If unclear, please update your question.

Comment: you totally misunderstood my questions.
let solve 2nd question first. i know the echo is needed when its get_the_title. my question is different. i just want to know how to get output if its inside php tag like this.
<?php
'<h2>'.the_title().'</h2>';
?>

Comment: `<?php echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>'; ?>`

Comment: That's ok But why this is not working:

`<?php 
while(have_posts()): the_post();
        
          '<h2>'.the_title().'</h2>';
         the_excerpt();
?>`

Comment: Becauce you can not just write `'<h2>' ... '</h2>'` inside PHP. You need to echo this. Or you do , `<?php echo '<h2>'; the_title(); echo '</h2>'; ?>` OR you do  `<?php echo '<h2>'.get_the_title().'</h2>; ?>`

Comment: Thanks got it. now come to first issue. why the reason its not working. its working outside php tags. but within php tags its not working.
`<?php
<a class="button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
?>`

Comment: still error....

Comment: Can you give me your complete code by editing your first post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69614/discussion-between-thedose-and-patrice-poliquin).